# Lost Password redirect to My Account

Tags: password

I’m facing an issue related to the lost password page and redirections.
I’m using woocommerce.

The link in the reset email : `https://mywebsite.com/my-account/lost-password/?key=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX&login=admin`

But when I access this url, I’m redirected to /my-account/, so no reset form…

But I don’t find a way to fix that!

Thanks for your help!

Comment: It is because you might have logged in to your account try to open the link in an incognito window. thanks

Comment: Yes, i am logged in from admin but resetting customer account password.
Is there any way to reset customer account password using reset link while i am logged in as Admin in same browser?

Comment: Using database or editing his profile might be the best when logged in as admin. Or try incognito/private mode of your browser and visit the link.